# MySQL show what a member not yet selected

Tags: php, mysql

We offer some bonuses for members to choose from and I want to show a popup with the bonuses they have not already selected. **bonus** contains info on the different bonuses, and **selected_bonuses** contains bonus id and the members id.

```
SELECT bonus.* FROM bonus 
LEFT JOIN selected_bonuses 
ON bonus.id = selected_bonuses.bonus_id 
WHERE selected_bonuses.member_id = 'xxxx'
```

This will show the bonuses selected for member 'xxxx'.

```
SELECT bonus.* FROM bonus 
LEFT JOIN selected_bonuses 
ON bonus.id = selected_bonuses.bonus_id 
WHERE selected_bonuses.member_id IS NULL
```

This show the bonuses not selected by any member. I want to show what bonuses just member 'xxxx' have not chosen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you use the following to show the bonuses which membor xxxx has not chosen?                                                    SELECT bonus.* FROM bonus 
LEFT JOIN selected_bonuses 
ON bonus.id = selected_bonuses.bonus_id 
WHERE selected_bonuses.member_id <> 'xxxx'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your query

```
SELECT bonus.* FROM bonus 
LEFT JOIN selected_bonuses 
ON bonus.id = selected_bonuses.bonus_id 
WHERE selected_bonuses.member_id = 'xxxx'
```

you join information about each bonus to each member having selected that bonus,
then select only one member.

If you instead join each bonus to just the member you are interested in, and
then select the bonuses for which no such member exists, you should get what you want:

```
SELECT bonus.* FROM bonus 
LEFT JOIN selected_bonuses 
ON bonus.id = selected_bonuses.bonus_id 
AND selected_bonuses.member_id = 'xxxx'
WHERE selected_bonuses.member_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do as Like Following ...

```
 SELECT bonus.* FROM bonus 
 LEFT JOIN selected_bonuses 
 ON bonus.id = selected_bonuses.member_id 
 WHERE (selected_bonuses.member_id = 'xxx' AND selected_bonuses.bonus_id IS NULL);
```

I think it will be work properly..

Comment: @Md. Maruf Hossain  This will select all bonuses that are selected by some other member, even if they are also selected by member xxxx, and will miss the ones that are not selected by any other member.

Comment: Now I sent another one ... Would you see that is **Correct** OR **Wrong**